# did the following steps now disk is not recognized!

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, mount

So I did this for a flashdrive and it worked perfectly then I tried it for an external harddrive and it will not work. After entering:

```
sudo mount -w -t msdos /dev/disk3s1 /Volumes/MIXTAPE
```

I get this output:

```
mount [-dfruvw] [-o options] [-t external_type] special node
       mount [-adfruvw] [-t external_type]
       mount [-dfruvw] special | node
```

Please help! it will not let me recognize any disk at all when plugged in

Steps followed and worked for flashdrive but failed for other...
From the terminal:

Identify your USB by NAME and IDENTIFIER:

```
diskutil list
```

Output is:

```
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):  
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE    IDENTIFIER  
0:               FDisk_partition_scheme              *2.0 GB     disk3
1:                 DOS_FAT_32 MIXTAPE                 2.0 GB   disk3s1
```

In this case, NAME=MIXTAPE and the IDENTIFIER=/dev/disk3s1

Now unmount the USB:

```
sudo diskutil unmount /dev/$IDENTIFIER
```

Example:

```
sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk3s1
```

Output is:

```
Volume MIXTAPE on disk3s1 unmounted
```

Now create the Volume directory - this appears to be the key!

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/$NAME
```

Example:

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/MIXTAPE
```

No output.

Now mount the USB to the Volume:

```
sudo mount -w -t msdos /dev/disk3s1 /Volumes/$NAME
```

Example:

```
sudo mount -w -t msdos /dev/disk3s1 /Volumes/MIXTAPE
```

No output.

Validate that the USB is now writeable:

```
touch /Volumes/$NAME/tmp.txt
```

Example:

```
touch /Volumes/MIXTAPE/tmp.txt
```

You should now be able to see that you were able to create the tmp.txt file on your USB in the Finder app or by:

```
ls -al /Volumes/$NAME
```

Example:

```
ls -al /Volumes/MIXTAPE
```

Comment: What you have done doesn't make sense. The flash drive is format as an msDos.  I is unlikely that your hd is formatted for dos.  Start from scratch.  There is no need to mount macOS devices. What happens when you plug the device into your mac?

Comment: It recognized the device but it is only in read only, i followed these steps to change that

Comment: no matter what i do, msdos, exfat, anytime i erase it the drive is still only read only

Comment: It would be read only if the drive was formatted for ntfs. Which is likely since it is a harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

You could be experiencing a hardware issue.  It could be a problem with your hd enclosure.  But, let's try this. Maybe the format didn't take and you still have the disk formatted for NTFS.  In terminal, run:

```
 diskutil list
```

Run this command before and after you attempt to format the drive. Post back the before and after lists.

Do you want to share with Windows?  For now, let's set it up for the mac. I suggest going with the most common setup for an external disk.

[image: disk utility]

[image: disk utility]